# How to put multiple objects in a mutableListOf in Kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin, object, mutablelist

I'm trying to put some objects in a mutableListOf, but all of them ended up overriding.

```
class Users {...}

class dbUsers{
var users = Users()
val list = mutableListOf(users)

fun addUser(phone: Int, name: String){
    users.phone = phone
    users.name = name
    list.add(users)
}
}

fun main() {
var dbAccess = dbUsers()
dbAccess.addUser(8439, "Thiago")
dbAccess.addUser(12312, "Maria")
println(dbAccess.list[0].name)
println(dbAccess.list[1].name)
}
```

When We print at position 1, we see that was override

Comment: Upload the Users class as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have initialized `Users` object only once, at the class level in `dbUsers`. You need to create new object everytime before adding the user to the list. Move the `users` initialization within the method instead

```
class dbUsers{
   
   val list = mutableListOf<Users>()

   fun addUser(phone: Int, name: String){
     var users = Users()
     users.phone = phone
     users.name = name
     list.add(users)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `list` is referencing from `users` and since `users` itself is updated every time, you get this results.

There are two ways you can approach this issue ,

1. Creating a new user every-time calling `addUser` , this is easy
2. If you have other data in `Users` than `name` and `phone` , you can just make a DeepCopy of your object by add in a new function in your class `copy()` like

```
class YourClass () {

// Your class other stuffs here

  fun copy(): YourClass { //Get another instance of YourClass with the values like this!
      val json = Gson().toJson(this)
      return Gson().fromJson(json, YourClass::class.java)
  }
}
```

then by using yourClassObject.copy() you will get a new instance with same values

```
fun addUser(phone: Int, name: String){
    val newUsers = users.copy()
    newUsers.phone = phone
    newUsers.name = name
    list.add(newUsers)
}
```